# Populated Places Names

Tags: data, natural-earth, places

I downloaded both Natural Earth's populated places .shp files but neither has the populated name place that I need, it is quite a large regional town which I would have expected to see but is not listed - Is it possible to add additional populated name places into the attributes table with Long/Lat or is there a more detailed .shp file with more populated name places I can download from somewhere else?

[image: These are the two .shp I used]

These are the two .shp files I used and neither has the place name that I wanted

Comment: If it's open data that you are asking about then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: I'm not sure what open data is - the .shp file of populated places is to use in QGIS

Comment: ["Open data, as defined by the Open Definition, is any kind of data that can be freely used, modified, and shared by anyone for any purpose."](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  I consider Natural Earth Data to be open data.  https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=natural+earth

Comment: @213 is it in OpenStreetMap?

Comment: As I am very new to QGIS and only been trying .shp from natural earth - I reckon it would be in OpenStreetMap but there would also be too much other data

Comment: can you provide the download link you used?

Comment: https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to solve this problem by creating my own CSV file with the exact places I require with Town Names and the Long/Lat position and their hierarchical level - I will then open up a new layer shapefile and upload the CSV file

Answer (score 0):

One good source for place name is : [Geonames page of The National Geospatial-Intelligence Agency](http://geonames.nga.mil/gns/html/namefiles.html) (US government) who give file for the whole world, it come as several .txt file (tab separated value) for each country, each .txt file beeing for a different kind a place . (you will find link for each country but the USA and all info about these data on the linked page)

Be careful as the locations are not always accurate (could be off up to 100 or 1000 meters sometime) but it seem to have most of city, town, hamlet and small populated place as well as a lot of non populated place like mountain, rivers, forest, name of point of interest and other geographical feature. I would say it is as complete as what google map display if not more complete (of course disregarding street name/adresses...) for the small area I checked